# Output whole row from list if duplicate has been found

Tags: c#, linq

I have a part of code that outputs duplicates from list. However it is giving only duplicates in particular column. How to output whole row if duplicate has been found?

Here is current code for finding duplicates:

```
var duplicatesPOSTADR = results.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dr => dr.POSTADR.Trim())
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Then I have another part that is sending an email message if duplicates has been found:

```
if (duplicatesPOSTADR?.Any() != false)
{
  string combindedString = string.Join(", ", duplicatesPOSTADR.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
  string EmailBody = "There was an error and following duplicates has been found in POSTADR column: " + combindedString;
  CreateMailItem(EmailBody);
}
```

So lets say I have data:

```
NRO   SNAME  NAMEA   NAMEB   IADDRESS  POSTA   POSTN   POSTADR   COMPANYN   COUNTRY   BID
423   Fiat   Punto   500     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JT        S1
463   BMW    E64     SE0     JR        KE      OT      P4        OL         J8        U9
483   KIA    E89     S78     J7        K7      O9      P6        O5         J4        U6
```

Now as an output I get:

```
P4
```

However I would like to get:

```
423   Fiat   Punto   500     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JT        S1
463   BMW    E64     SE0     JR        KE      OT      P4        OL         J8        U9
```

Any hints how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying the `.Select(dr => dr.POSTADR.Trim())` statement in your code, the end result will only contain the `POSTADR` `string` values.

Just do the grouping without this projection.
This results in an `IEnumerable` of your full class instances that have doubles in `POSTADR`.

```
var duplicatesPOSTADR = 
    results.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => x.POSTADR.Trim())
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(g => g)
        ;
```

Answer (score 3):

After your grouping you need to select the records from the group instead of the key. You could use something like this:

```
var duplicatesPOSTADR = results.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr => dr.POSTADR.Trim())
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for this! In my case it outputs all the duplicates. So not only unique results, but both values if they are duplicates. So not `P4`, but `P4, P4`. I would like to see all other data from this row as well. For example I have NAME, ID, COUNTRY, CITY etc. in other columns.

Comment: @TeaBaerd did you really just edited your answer copying mine?

Comment: @pfx - i condensed the initial select and subsequent GroupBy to address OP's comment. You will notice mine still has the ToList which it initially contained that yours did not. I upvoted your answer recognizing it as accurate at the same time i made the correction from OPs comment.

Comment: @pfx you were welcome to edit my answer to incorporate the OPs feedback before I was able to address it. Instead it appears you posted the answer separately.

Comment: I don't know which one should I choose now as an answer as both are the same